# Getting "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named" when Maven build is run with Junit testcases

Tags: jpa, junit, h2, h2db

When running the maven build with Junit getting "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named" error.Not able to identify what is missing in my code.

Main class:

```
public class ApprovalHistory {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Approval_History")  
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApprovalHistory.class);

    public EntityManagerFactory emfactory = null;

    final String JDBC_URL_H2DB = "jdbc:h2:file:./APApproval/ApprovalHistoryH2DB";
    final String JDBC_USERNAME_H2DB = "";
    final String JDBC_PASSWORD_H2DB = "";

    final String JDBC_DRIVER_SQL = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    final String JDBC_DRIVER_H2 = "org.h2.Driver";
    final String JDBC_DRIVER_HSQL = "org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver";

    final String PERSISTANCE_UNIT_NAME = "Approval_History";

    final String SELECT_BO_TABLE = "SELECT bobj FROM BusinessObjectTable bobj where bobj.docId =:";
    final String SELECT_COMMENT_TABLE = "SELECT comment FROM CommentTable comment where comment.actionTable.id IN :";
    final String SELECT_REASON_TABLE = "SELECT reason FROM ReasonTable reason where reason.actionTable.id IN :";    

    public ApprovalHistory()
    {
        try {
            createEntityManagerFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void insertData(List<ApprovalHistoryModel> historyList){

        if(historyList != null && !historyList.isEmpty())
        {
            EntityManager entitymanager = null;

            try
            {           
                entitymanager = getEntityManager();
                entitymanager.getTransaction().begin(); 


                ApprovalHistoryModel firstItem = historyList.get(0);

                ActionTable a = new ActionTable(firstItem.actionType, firstItem.tenantId, firstItem.comment, firstItem.reason);

                for(ApprovalHistoryModel h : historyList) 
                {
                    a.getBusinessObjects().add(new BusinessObjectTable(h.userName, h.taskId, h.docId, h.objectIdentifier1, h.objectIdentifier2, h.objectIdentifier3,h.tenantId));
                }

                entitymanager.persist(a);

                entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();                    
            }
            catch (RuntimeException e) {
                if(entitymanager!=null && entitymanager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                    entitymanager.getTransaction().rollback();
                }
                throw e;
            }

            finally{
                closeEntityManager(entitymanager);
            }
        }
    }


    public List<ApprovalHistoryModel> getApprovalHistory(String docID) throws Exception
    {
        logger.info("=ApprovalConnector=: start of getApprovalHistory()");

        List<ApprovalHistoryModel> historyModels = new ArrayList<ApprovalHistoryModel>();

        if(docID!=null && !docID.isEmpty()) {
        EntityManager entitymanager = null;

        try
        {
            entitymanager = getEntityManager();     

            TypedQuery<BusinessObjectTable> bobjquery =  entitymanager.createQuery(SELECT_BO_TABLE+"DocID ",BusinessObjectTable.class);
            bobjquery.setParameter("DocID", docID);         
            List<BusinessObjectTable> bobjs = bobjquery.getResultList();    

            if(bobjs!=null){
                for (BusinessObjectTable bobj : bobjs) {
                    ActionTable a = bobj.getActionTable();

                    ApprovalHistoryModel history = new ApprovalHistoryModel();
                    history.docId = bobj.getDocId();
                    history.taskId = bobj.getApprovalItemId();
                    history.userName = bobj.getUserName();

                    logger.debug("=ApprovalConnector=: getApprovalHistory(): documentID - "+bobj.getDocId());
                    history.actionType = a.getActionType();

                    logger.debug("=ApprovalConnector=: getApprovalHistory(): actionType - "+ history.actionType);

                    history.actionDate = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(new DateTime(a.getActionDate()));
                    history.objectIdentifier1 = bobj.getObjectIdentifier1();
                    history.objectIdentifier2=bobj.getObjectIdentifier2();
                    history.objectIdentifier3 = bobj.getObjectIdentifier3();
                    history.tenantId = a.getTenantId();

                    history.comment = a.getComment()!=null?a.getComment().getComment():"";
                    history.reason = a.getReason()!=null?a.getReason().getReason():"";

                    historyModels.add(history);
                }

            }
            logger.info("=ApprovalConnector=: end of getApprovalHistory()");
        }
        finally{
            closeEntityManager(entitymanager);
        }   
    }

        return historyModels;
    }

    public void createEntityManagerFactory() throws Exception
    {               
        Map<String, String> persistenceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String jdbcDriver = getJdbcDriverName(JDBC_URL_H2DB);

        persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", jdbcDriver);
        persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", JDBC_URL_H2DB);

        if (!JDBC_USERNAME_H2DB.isEmpty()) {
            persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", JDBC_USERNAME_H2DB);
        }
        if (!JDBC_PASSWORD_H2DB.isEmpty()) {
            persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", JDBC_PASSWORD_H2DB);
        }

        persistenceMap.put("eclipselink.session-name",System.currentTimeMillis() + "");

        this.emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTANCE_UNIT_NAME, persistenceMap); 

    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager()
    {               
        EntityManager entitymanager = this.emfactory.createEntityManager();
        return entitymanager;
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(EntityManager entitymanager)
    {
        if(entitymanager!=null)
            entitymanager.close();      
    }
    public void closeEntityManagerFactory()
    {
        if(this.emfactory!=null)
            this.emfactory.close();
    }

    private String getJdbcDriverName(String jdbcUrl) {
        if (jdbcUrl.startsWith("jdbc:sqlserver"))
            return JDBC_DRIVER_SQL;
        if (jdbcUrl.startsWith("jdbc:h2"))
            return JDBC_DRIVER_H2;
        if (jdbcUrl.startsWith("jdbc:hsqldb"))
            return JDBC_DRIVER_HSQL;
        return null;
    }



Test Calss:

    public class ApprovalHistoryTest {

        ApprovalHistory approvalHistory = new ApprovalHistory();

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {

            List<ApprovalHistoryModel> actionHistoryModels = new ArrayList<ApprovalHistoryModel>();     

                for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
                ApprovalHistoryModel history = new ApprovalHistoryModel();
                String comment = "comment no. " + i;
                String reason = "reason no. " + i;
                String userName = "User" + i;
                history.taskId = "321YZ61_0026CV7Z0000XB" + i;
                history.actionDate = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(new DateTime(new Date()));
                history.actionType = i;
                history.comment = comment.trim();
                history.docId = "321YZ61_026CV7Z0000TD" + i;
                history.userName = userName;
                history.reason = reason;

                actionHistoryModels.add(history);

                }   
            approvalHistory.insertData(actionHistoryModels);
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            DeleteApprovalHistory history = new DeleteApprovalHistory();
            try{
            history.purgeRecord(0,"DAYS");  
            approvalHistory.closeEntityManagerFactory();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }


        @Test()
        public void test() {
            //ApprovalHistory approvalHistory = new ApprovalHistory();
            List<ApprovalHistoryModel> historyList = new ArrayList<ApprovalHistoryModel>(); 
            for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
            ApprovalHistoryModel history = new ApprovalHistoryModel();
              try {
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                  historyList=approvalHistory.getApprovalHistory(history.docId);
                  assertEquals("321YZ61_0026CV7Z0000XB" + i,historyList.get(i).taskId);`enter code here`
                  assertEquals("comment no. " + i,historyList.get(i).comment);
                  assertEquals("User" + i,historyList.get(i).userName);
                  assertEquals("reason no. " + i,historyList.get(i).reason);
                  assertEquals(i,historyList.get(i).actionType);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            }
        }

    }

Persistence.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="Approval_History" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.perceptivesoftware.apapproval.history.ActionTable</class>
    <class>com.perceptivesoftware.apapproval.history.BusinessObjectTable</class>
    <class>com.perceptivesoftware.apapproval.history.CommentTable</class>
    <class>com.perceptivesoftware.apapproval.history.ReasonTable</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-cache" value="true" />          
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Error::

> Running ApprovalHistoryTest javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No
>   Persistence provider for EntityManager named Approval_History     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.perceptivesoftware.apapproval.history.ApprovalHistory.createEntityManagerFactory(ApprovalHistory.java:167)
>     at
>   com.perceptivesoftware.apapproval.history.ApprovalHistory.(ApprovalHistory.java:48)
>     at ApprovalHistoryTest.(ApprovalHistoryTest.java:20)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:187)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named Approval_History  at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.perceptivesoftware.apapproval.history.ApprovalHistory.createEntityManagerFactory(ApprovalHistory.java:167)
>     at
>   com.perceptivesoftware.apapproval.history.ApprovalHistory.(ApprovalHistory.java:48)
>     at
>   com.perceptivesoftware.apapproval.history.DeleteApprovalHistory.purgeRecord(DeleteApprovalHistory.java:46)
>     at ApprovalHistoryTest.tearDown(ApprovalHistoryTest.java:50)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:36)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

Comment: persistence.xml needs to be in META-INF from the root of the CLASSPATH. All required jars for the JPA implementation need to be present. Those are not things a user here can check for you

Answer (score 0):

You've annotated the wrong attribute:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "Approval_History")  
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApprovalHistory.class);
```

Should be:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "Approval_History")  
public EntityManager em;
```

The @PersistenceContext annotation injects an EntityManager into your code, which is created from the EntityManagerFactory associated with the persistence unit that you specify ("Approval_History" in your case).

Comment: As a quick sanity check, you do have a persistence.xml file which defines a persistence unit called Approval_History?  If so, can you edit your question with its contents and relative location in your project?

Comment: Persistence is under META-INF which lies directly under the project.

Comment: Maybe your META-INF is in the incorrect place?  It should be ${project.root}/src/main/resources/META_INF

Comment: I got the issue...META-INF shud be in the classpath....after adding it forcefully I cud overcome the error.

Comment: Any idea how we can place META-INF programtically into classpath?Can it be done using pom.xml?

Comment: @abcd123 that entirely depends on what you are trying to achieve.  I wouldnt recommend doing it via the maven pom, unless you plan on including it as a bundle resource at compile time.